# как перевернуть строку Hello world! на !dlrow olleH

Tags: python

То есть мне нужно решение этой задачи и какие символы нужно использовать чтобы, когда я ввел код  в IDLE SHELL код Hello world! у меня в программе вышло наоборот !dlrow olleH

Comment: Символы тоже должны зеркально отразиться?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: @YaAlex да все зеркально

Answer (score 4):

Переворот строки достигается за счёт среза. Работает это следующим образом, имеем срез вида `[begin:end:step]` начало и конец опускаем, шаг задаем `-1`, за счет этого строка печатается начиная с конца.

```py
print('Hello world!') # <- вывод: Hello world!
print('Hello world!'[::-1]) # <- вывод: !dlrow olleH
```